# How can I specify the position of editText in CardView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-cardview

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/heightText"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the EditText code I placed inside the CardView.

[image]

How can I change the location of the editText placed as in the image as I wish? For example, when I try to hold the editText with the mouse, it automatically returns to its position in the image. It's like it's magnetized to the top left corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To position views within a `CardView` you need to nest them in a layout container view, like a `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc. *inside* the CardView.

Here is an example using a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/heightText"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" 
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

then you can use the rules of the layout container to position them properly.

If your CardView had dynamic height (`wrap_content`) you would want to also set the ConstraintLayout view height to `wrap_content` too instead of `match_parent`.

If you only have a single view that you want to put in the card, you could also control its position using `android:layout_gravity` attributes instead of using a layout container. [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView) inherits from [`FrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), so the same guidance about positioning views applies:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.